# providing HTTP interface

Tags: http, networking, https, tcp, network-programming

I am working on a task which basically is "Providing HTTP interface and move out of TCP". Thats what I know so far.

What I am looking for is:

1] "Providing HTTP interface" What does this translate to exactly. I mean after achieving what steps I can conclude that this task to be done ?

2] What more information/questions I need to understand/ask for getting this done.

What I am trying to do is understand the problem space better and also look for any solutions[patterns] widely used to fix this in the "right" way.

Any suggestions/pointers would be great.

Thankx.

Comment: What is your application? How does the current version work?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you're being asked to migrate a service currently offered through a proprietary application protocol served over TCP/IP.

As a member pointed already, you will never "move out of TCP" since the HTTP version is highly probable to use TCP/IP anyway. But we all understand what your boss/client is trying to say. What is requested is probably a web service as we know it today. And yes, using HTTP as a basis is the right way to do it.

Knowing that, you are now faced with two alternatives:

### 1) Present a function-oriented service

Here you list the commands that the service can handle and you implement them following a classical `function(argument) => result` style.

For this approach I recommend using the [JSON-RPC model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC)

### 2) Present a data-oriented service

Here you list the information that is moving in and out of your service and implement the operations occurring on these pieces of information, following the REST cycle `data OPERATION response`

For this approach I recommend using the [REST style](http://rest.blueoxen.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?FrontPage)

### How to choose ?

In a nutshell:

- If you have to serve few clients AND the set of commands is small and simple, go with RPC.
- If you must serve many clients OR the problem domain is complex, go with REST.

Whatever approach you go for, always prefer JSON over XML unless XML is mandated.

Answer (score 0):

Is your current process doing raw TCP sockets connections?

It almost sounds like they want an HTTP web service instead of raw TCP.

But I think much more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

a rough guess would be that someone wants a web front-end to something that probably is done at a command-line level now...  you should really ask for a few more details, or post what details you were given..

Answer (score 0):

> Providing HTTP interface and move out of TCP

HTTP operates at the application layer of the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), whereas TCP operates at the transport layer.  This basically means that HTTP operates on top of TCP.

> What does this translate to exactly

The HTTP 1.1 specification is defined in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).  To be truly HTTP 1.1 compliant, you must implement the protocol as defined in this RFC.

> What more information/questions I need to understand/ask for getting this done

I would also ask what sorts of clients will be connecting to this server (browser, custom client, other services).  Get a specification sheet with as many details as possible and get the client to commit to what functionality they need: there's nothing worse than having to rewrite stuff on a whim because a CEO saw a new acronym in his mailbox this morning.